# Помогите перегрузить оператор потокового ввода\вывода с++

Tags: c++, вывод, операторы, перегрузка-операторов

Доброго времени суток. Где я допустил ошибку? Перегрузка оператора как-будто игнорируется. Выводит просто "test", а я ожидаю "[INFO]: test".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "Trigon.hpp"

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &out, const char* &a){
    out << "[INFO]: " << a << std::endl;
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::cout << "test";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неужели столь нубский вопрос?) Хоть наводку дайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас неправильный тип аргумента в функции `const char* &`, поэтому перегруженная функция не вызывается.

Во-вторых, она у вас рекурсивная и вызывает сама себя.

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "Trigon.hpp"

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &out, const char* a){
    out << std::string("[INFO]: ") << std::string(a) << std::endl;
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::cout << "test";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Поясните пожалуйста каким образом перегрузка вызывает сама себя.

Comment: А, все. Сообразил :)

Comment: Хуже того, для `const char*` уже определён вывод через `ostream`. Поэтому если вам удастся сделать правильную перезагрузку, то вы нарушите One Definition Rule с плачевным последствиями.

Comment: @VladD а если так `namespace  {
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &out, const char* a){...}}`

Comment: @zenden2k: Классный вопрос! Не знаю, думаю, стоит спросить у наших language lawyer'ов.